# I cannot rearrange UITabBarItem(s) in the UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

As soon as I add a third bar item to the UITabBar I cannot rearrange the items from the storyboard (which works when I have just two bar items). I am not sure what I am missing. I do not want to do it programmatically and feel that Xcode should allow me to do what I am enable to do right now. Any suggestions? What do you think is the problem?

I am running xcode 4.5 and developing for iOS6.

Thanks

p.s. this issue is so silly that is driving me crazy, please help! I am almost embarrassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is to disconnect all the relationship and connect again in the right order.
It seems stupid, but it works.
I don't know if there is another procedure to do it.

Regards
Fabio